# Double Bar Graph Using Prawn in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn, prawnto

Can any one tell me how to draw double bar graph using prawn in rails 3.2 in PDF File. I am able to get the single bar graph on PDF but i dont know how to draw double bar graph in PDF File. Is there any way to create more than single bar using prawn or is there any other gem which can do this but I dont want to use other gem in the middle of my project So if any one could help me that would be grateful.Thanks

Comment: Do you use _prawn-graph_ in your project? If no, how do you render a single bar graph?

Comment: Yes i am using prawn-graph in my rails application

Answer (score 0):

I think its too late but it can still be helpful to someone else.
using [prawn-graph](https://github.com/HHRy/prawn-graph)

**Example**:

```
require 'prawn-graph'

series = []
series << Prawn::Graph::Series.new([4,9,3,2,1,6,2,8,2,3,4,9,2],  title: "A label for a series", type: :bar)

series << Prawn::Graph::Series.new([5,4,3,2,7,9,2,8,7,5,4,9,2],  title: "Another label", type: :line, mark_average: true, mark_minimum: true)

series << Prawn::Graph::Series.new([1,2,3,4,5,9,6,4,5,6,3,2,11], title: "Yet another label", type: :bar)

series << Prawn::Graph::Series.new([1,2,3,4,5,12,6,4,5,6,3,2,9].shuffle, title: "One final label", type: :line, mark_average: true, mark_maximum: true)

xaxis_labels = ['0900', '1000', '1100', '1200', '1300', '1400', '1500', '1600', '1700', '1800', '1900', '2000', '2100']

Prawn::Document.generate('test.pdf') do

    graph series, width: 500, height: 200, title: "A Title for the chart", at: [10,700], xaxis_labels: xaxis_labels

end
```